# Dynkin Operator explained to a finance student

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Can somone gives me an introduction about the so-called Dynkin Operator ?
(finance student means that I know stochastic calculus only at an introductory level without a solid background in funtional analysis, measure theory, ...)
\begin{equation}
D(X(t)):=\frac{d}{dt}{E}(X(t))
\end{equation}
I have met it studying stochastic calculus for finance to compute the moments of Ito processes, using this equality:
\begin{equation}
\frac{E(d(x(t))}{dt}=\frac{dE(X(t))}{dt}
\end{equation}
(I am taking it from Baz,J.,Chacko,G., Financial derivatives p. 227)

For instance, here's an example with an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.
\begin{equation}
dX(t)=k[\theta-X(t)]dt+\sigma dW(t)
\end{equation}
From the previous equality follows that
\begin{equation}
\frac{dE(X(t))}{dt}=k \theta-k E(X(t))
\end{equation}
This is a simple ODE that can be solved subject to $E(X(0))=x_0$ and so we obtain
\begin{equation}
E(X(t))=\theta+(x_0-\theta)e^{-kt}
\end{equation}

However, I do not know anything about its interpretation, about the reason beacuse the above equality it's true and moreover I usually see it written in a much more complicated form.
For instance, it seems to me that it is related to the infinitesimal generator, defined as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}f(x)= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{E^x[f(X_T)]-f(x)}{t}
\end{equation}

UPDATE

I've discovered reading Bjork,T., Arbitrage theory in continuous time, that Dynkin operator is also called Infinitesimal operator, or Ito operator or Kolmogorov backward operator. He defines it in the following way:
given
\begin{equation}
dX_t=\mu (t,X_t) dt + \sigma (t,X_t),dW_t
\end{equation}
the infinitesimal operator of $X$ is defined for any function $h(x) \in C^2(R^n)$ by
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}h(t,x)= \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i(t,x) \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i}
(x)+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j=1}^n C_{ij}(t,x) \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(x)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
C(t,x)=\sigma(t,x)\sigma^*(t,x)
\end{equation}

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add some references where you read that please. The left hand side of your equation makes no sense to me.

Comment: You need to say more about what "non-math student" means. Does this mean no math beyond  elementary calculus (differential, integral, and multivariable) and differential equations, or nothing beyond elementary differential and integral calculus, or nothing beyond elementary differential calculus (but at a college level where, for example, students would be exposed to *statements* of the mean value theorem and intermediate value theorem for continuous functions), or nothing beyond a first semester U.S. business calculus course, or nothing beyond high school precalculus, or  . . . ??

Comment: Dynkin's formula is familiar; is it related to "Dynkin's operator" as Baz & Chacko use the term?

Comment: They always say operator. However, it seems to me that the two are related, indeed I think that what they defined Dynkin operator is very similar to the so-called infinitesimal generator, a sort of derivative of the expected value (at least formally)

Comment: Just had a look into the chapter of the book you cited. Don't waste your time on it. It's trashy.

Comment: Why do you think that it is trashy ? In my view, we have to wait for somone who understands the math to find if their presentation is bad or incorrect.

Comment: I do understand the maths pretty well, otherwise I wouldn't judge. The identity they use is simply stupid or saying it more elegantly, the authors certainly don't foster a usage of common and rigourous maths language. Apart, this identity is not necessary for what they do afterwards for OU process. As John Dawkins pointed out already Dynkins formua tells you how to deal with $d/dt \mathbb{E}[f(X_{t})]$ and there indeed the generator of the process appears. Probably, if you want to understand these things better you should look into a book or lecture notes on stochastic analysis, not finance.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your position. I thought that you were not familiar beacuse you did not answer my question. So, as far as I understand $d/dtE[f(Xt)]$ and $\mathcal{A}f(x)=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{E^x(f(X_T)-f(x)}{t}$ are the same thing and although it is not a derivative of the expected value when I set the ODE I can think of it in this way right ?

Comment: Not really. Under some integrability assumptions you would have $d/dt\mathbb{E}[f(X_{t})]=\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{A}f(X_{t})]$ which essentially is the Fokker-Planck equation.

Comment: Ok, last thing. For an OU, from the equation above we know that $\frac{d(E(X_t))}{dt}=k \theta -k E(X_t)$ now you say me that $\frac{d(E(X_t))}{dt}=E[\mathcal{A}f(X_t)]$, since $\mathcal{A}f(X_t)=k \theta - k x f'(x) + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} f''(x)$ it means that $E[f'(x)]=1$ and $E[f''(x)= 0$, correct, and if so why?

Comment: Dynkins formula applies to compactely supported $C^{2}$ functions, therefore in order to calculate $d/dt\mathbb{E}[X_{t}]$, i.e. $f(x)=x$, you can actually not use it. It does yield the right result however, since $f''=0$ and $f'=1$.